# axios-curlirize npm not printing proxy in console log

Tags: node.js, express, npm, curl, axios

I am using **axios** and **axios-curlirize** npm libraries in my code. It is working for all API calls. But one of my API is using a proxy, when I hit that API axios-curlirize package prints **curl request** for it in console, but it doesn't print the complete curl request for that API including the proxy settings.

I want to get the complete curl request with proxy settings in it.

I am using these libraries. When I make a hit to my API, I get this in console.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import curlirize from 'axios-curlirize';
curlirize(axios);

curl -X GET "http://host:port/url" -H "Authorization:Basic token"
```

But I am not getting the complete curl request with proxy settings in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no support for proxy in axios-curlirize.**

You can use -x arg on the command line for proxy parameters.

```
curl -x 'http://proxy_host:proxy_port' 'http://api_host:api_port/some-url' -H "Authorization:Basic some_token"
```